# Une nuance entre « tout bonnement » et « tout simplement »

Tags: choix-de-mot

> [j’ai dit] : Peu importe le point de vue qu’on a sur la Skytree, elle est **tout bonnement** splendide.
>
> [au lieu de] : Peu importe le point de vue qu’on a sur la Skytree, elle est **tout simplement** splendide.

Je m’interroge sur la différence entre les deux, que ce soit celle de sens, d’usage, de registre ou de quoi que ce soit d'autre. À moins qu’ils ne soient interchangeables l'un avec l'autre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le sens de « tout [bonnement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bonnement) » a légèrement évolué avec le temps mais la différence principale se situe surtout dans la fréquence d'utilisation. « Tout [simplement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/simplement) » a toujours été plus courant et [son usage est en progression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tout%20bonnement%2Ctout%20simplement&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctout%20bonnement%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btout%20bonnement%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTout%20bonnement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctout%20simplement%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btout%20simplement%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTout%20simplement%3B%2Cc0) alors que « tout bonnement » reste beaucoup plus rare.

Comment: Hi. Is this expression considered "rare" because it is kind of old-fashioned?

Comment: Not really, it has always been rarer but it is still usable nowadays.